# How can I wrap text in lists without adding linebreaks?

Tags: vim, indentation, word-wrap

In all the years that I have been using VIM, I have never been able to "wrap" the text in lists as below.

Wrap off:

```
- this is a list entry with an amount of text that can exceed 100 characters.
```

Wrap on:

```
- this is a list entry with an amount of text that can 
exceed 100 characters.
```

Expected with wrap on:

```
- this is a list entry with an amount of text that can 
  exceed 100 characters.
```

My settings:

```
"comments
set comments=f:-,f:*
"see this as list
let &formatlistpat='^\s*\([-*]\|\d\{1,2}[a-z]\?[.)]\|\a[.)]\)\s\+'
"format options
set formatoptions=tcqnw
```

How can I wrap the text (in lists) as expected (**without adding linebreaks**).
Not all text, only the text in lists.

Comment: `setl wrap breakindent breakindentopt=shift:2`

Comment: Can't believe it! Thank you very much! If you want put it in an answer below so I can accept your answer and we can close the question.

Comment: @Matt, Your setting also indents the normal text. I would like to use the breakindent only for bullet lists and numbered lists. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Without inserting real newlines and spaces? I'm not sure if it's possible at all.

Comment: @Matt, text is already wrapped if wrap is enabled. Don't want the wrapped text to be intended. Only lists.

Comment: I see what you want but you want too much. Just keep real spaces as produced by `formatoptions` and `formatlistpat`.